# Background worker return value?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

```
private float bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

I'm trying to make the thread method to return a value but I get

```
Assets/Scripts/test.cs(574,71): error CS0407: A method or delegate float test.bw_DoWork(object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)' return type does not match delegate `void System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)' return type
```

what's the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
This should do the trick. Keep in mind you will need to return your values differently you cannot return in a thread. The best way is to Invoke inside a separate thread.

private string  ReturnObject {get;set;}
DoWork(){

UpdateValues("My Value");
}     

UpdateValues(string _value){
MethodInvoker action = delegate
                {
                   //Controls Mehtods HERE
ReturnObject = _value;
                };

     this.Invoke(action)
}
```